# pip3 error; Unable to upgrade csvkit (anaconda installed)

Tags: bash, csv, ubuntu

I am creating errors while updating csvkit due to some dependencies.
How can I fix them?

```
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
```

[Bash errors showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9UzS.jpg)

Comment: The first command failed because the -d should be passed to 'csvstat', not 'cat', like so: cat demo1.csv | csvstat -d ','

Comment: Thx. Got that fixed

Comment: Does this answer your original question?  If yes, I'll post it as the official answer.

Comment: it answers one of my subquestions. thanks